# Can 't send mail using OnedriveApp on AppsScript

Tags: google-apps-script

Im using OnedriveApp which is Google Apps Script library written by tanaikech but after deloyed function doGet(e) and succeed get token i try to send email function like this and no mail in my gmail.
The log return [undefined] as image below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nipxb.png)

Some one with same problem and solved or the question reach the author.

Comment: Please post code - [format code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)